# Sharepoint 2013 Central Admin problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, internal-server-error

This error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you are visiting had a server problem which prevented the webpage from displaying.[image]

[image: error trace details]

Please help me out i am new to the sharepoint administration

Comment: is it fresh installation? how many servers in the farm?

Comment: So, if I I get this correctly, this is a message you get when trying to access the central administration site? The part about the missing SPNativeRequestModule seems a little odd... what environment is this? A prod or a dev one? Any chance you may be seeing the results of a corrupted or incomplete installation? I have I am far more skilled into SharePoint development than administration, but if I had to take a guess I would check if you are able to access any other site on the farm.

Comment: From what I can gather, that module is a core component in the whole way SharePoint works, since it is responsible in a way to "handle" all requests at the lower layer. Having IIS reporting it as "missing" seems pretty worrying

Comment: Yes its central admin and no site is accessible on the farm

Comment: its a stand alone environment and its DEV server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a way here but as i don't have the product configuration key or PARAPHRASE KEY i could not retrieve the old content database.

- Create a New content database
- then start the Sharepoint product configuration wizard
  NEXT--> YES --> Connect to an existing server farm-->database server name and database name-->and then configure this as new farm and it gives the new central admin and you can start from there with creating new site collections and you can also link the previous content databases to the existing new site collections so that you can retrieve the data